# OP rejected my edit and then copy-pasted it

Tags: discussion

I suggested an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1175041/2) to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1175041/1) a few days ago. The edit was approved by a moderator, but was then rejected by the OP of the answer. Which is totally fine, since my interpretation of what the OP wanted to say could be different from what they actually wanted to say.

However, the OP later edited their answer and copy-pasted my edit (I suppose from the Markdown Preview, since only the code tags are missing), as one can see in their [edited answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1175041/618353).

I don't have a problem with the rejection of an edit in general from a more experienced user or the OP (it's the OP's post after all) nor the -2 reputation points make a big difference. But, many times, when suggesting an edit, an editor spends a significant amount of time trying to decipher and state clearly what the OP wants to say and I don't think that the edit rejection is fair in a case like this particular one.

In the end, the post is improved either way, which is the goal of an editor, but, in this case, the OP didn't even copy the suggestion properly, leading to a less easy to read post than that of the suggested edit.

Is this behavior acceptable in general? What can an editor do in such a case? Just accept the rejection? Comment under the OP's post and ask him to revert to the suggested edit? Make another edit suggestion?

Comment: Don't worry, it happens. It happened to me as well. But as terdon said, there's nothing you can do. On a side note you're just 107 reputation points away from editing posts without getting permission from OP **:-P**

Comment: @Kulfy I supposed that this is not so uncommon, but since I bumped into this case and didn't find another similar question, I thought that asking it could benefit others faced with this case too. And yes, I'm just a few days away from that milestone!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It looks like an honest misunderstanding. The OP is very new, so probably misclicked, then realized their mistake and tried to apply the edit the only way they knew how.

As for what you can do: nothing, really. You did your best. You suggested a useful edit, if the OP doesn't like that, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Yeah, it's really possible that this has happened. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @user3140225 As a former moderator this has also happened to me. I clicked the wrong button then started invoking the gods to try to give credit where credit is do. I normally do stuff like add on the answer "Thanks to X user for the fixes" or something to that effect.