# Edit suggestion was rejected by OP

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

While I believe I was [suggesting a helpful edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1108038), seems the community (conflict?) / OP believes otherwise. Was the edit not helpful?

Comment: Even though the suggested edit seems helpful the owner of the question rejected the edit for some unknown reason, and it is the privilege of the OP to do so for any reason.

Comment: @karel That is fine, what I was more looking for is whether my edit was really worth it, or I need to improve something? This reject was just one pair of eyes on it, you know?

Comment: The suggested edit looked OK to me.

Comment: @karel OK, thank you.

Comment: related: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18810/op-rejected-my-edit-and-then-copy-pasted-it

Comment: @Dan true, but here OP did not take any action, which leaves the question in the bad state.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have a feeling that it was rejected, because OP did not want to lose the "*please help me*" bit. It was way more important to them than any other aspect. And they don't really understand the reviewers' intentions, because probably they have zero idea about the StackExchange concept of trying to raise posts to a higher standard. It takes a little time participating on StackExchange sites to get the hang of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggested edit looked OK to me. Even though the suggested edit seems helpful the owner of the question rejected the edit for some unknown reason, and it is the privilege of the OP to do so for any reason.